# Handling Large dataset for analysis

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, data-science, tfidfvectorizer

I hope someone can help me with this. I am new to working with large datasets and need help optimizing run time and also memory usage.

I am working with news articles with articles from 30 newspapers between 2000-2018. There are approximately 12 million articles in the entire dataset. I am working on calculating TFIDF and cosine similarity between the articles and given that data is around 40GB, I am not sure how well it will scale.

At the moment I am only working with data of 1 month and while it works, it is extremely slow.

- For the TFIDF vocabulary building, the corpus duration will never exceed 1year data (that's the upper limit) on the duration of analysis we wish to perform. What is the best way to build vocabulary? I searched a bit around the internet and found that with gensim we can build vocabulary in an incremental way. Is that best I can do or is there a better/fast way to handle this?
- Given that I succeed with building the vocabulary for corpus, I need to calculate all the articles(from a particular date) which have cosine similarity less than a given threshold with other articles (for the same date). Since the vocabulary can huge, repeatedly calling transform and cosine_similarity can be quite expensive. Any idea how I can improve on this? I thought of using the Kruskal algorithm for finding disconnected components so as to minimize the call to transform and cosine_similarity.

While using iterator and gensim to build a dictionary in an iterating way might help save memory use, I am still not sure how to decrease the time for calculating the number of articles that have no similar articles?

3) If anyone has experience working with similar data in pandas, should I move to a database or is pandas sufficient for this task?

Thanks :)

Comment: To optimize run time and memory usage, use C++ (preferably with OpenMP).  Python is not designed to be efficient.  If you need Python, use Cython at least.

Comment: "the time for calculating the number of articles that have no similar articles" - please clarify

Comment: I was in a similar situation as you were (I used LSA instead of TFIDF), I decided to move to a database and it worked better. While using pandas, the main problem is you are limited to your system RAM. I am pretty sure your DB would be hosted on a server with much better capabilities.

Comment: @user31264 "the time for calculating the number of articles that have no similar articles", What I mean here, is I have a list of articles (say for a date) and I want to find out number of those articles for which there is no other article in the list such that the cosine similarity is greater than threshold.

Comment: @Gary did you use sqlite3 or some other database. I moved my data to sqlite3 db which is 40GB but the queries are still slow.

Comment: Where is your DB being hosted ? The capabilities of the server hosting your DB will also determine the speed of your query execution (apart from proper table indexing and others). Mine was an oracle db with extremely fast server performance.

Comment: @Gary It's hosted on my department's cluster but the cluster isn't really very powerful. I created an index on (month, year) since I will almost always be fetching data filtered by date and it seems to be working much better :)

Comment: @Gary and did you use gensim for LSA?

Comment: No, I used lsalib!